# python groupby calculate ratio

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have some simple code that does a multi-groupby (first on the date column, second on the cp_flag column) and calculates an aggregated sum for each cp_flag per day.

`df.groupby(['date', 'cp_flag']).volume.sum()`

I would like to calculate the ratio between C and P (e.g. for 2015-01-02, return 170381/366072) without using .apply, .transform or .agg if possible. I can't quite figure out how to extend my current code to achieve this ratio calculation.

[image]

Edit:

The desired output would just be an individual series with the C/P ratio for each date, e.g.

```
2015-01-02  0.465
...
2020-12-31  0.309
```

Comment: Can you give an example of your desired results? I'm thinking that your best option might be to pivot the data so that C and P are there own columns then do whatever math you would like on them. Additionally, is there a reason you are trying not to use .apply since that is a big advantage of pandas?

Comment: do `.unstack()` to the output of your `groupby.sum`